# how to load hundred of images to bootstrap asp.net mvc by LazyLoad jQuery Plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading

I installed LazyLoading jquery plugin and try to use it in my bootstrap mvc project. In examples that I saw, address of just one image is set to  tag. I don't know how does it work.
How can I show all images by scrolling page. This is my Code.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Custom-Theme-files-->
<!--theme-style-->
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="~/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="~/Content/css/products.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

```
                    <div class="LazyImage">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 ">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 product-left p-left">
                                            <div class="product-main simpleCart_shelfItem">

                                                <img class="lazy" src="~/Content/images/grey.gif" data-original="../Content/images/LazyLoad/example.jpg" width="200" height="200" />

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        $("img.lazy").lazyload({
            //threshold = 100,
            //event = "sporty",
            placeholder : "/Content/images/grey.gif",
            event : "lazyload",
            effect : "fadeIn",
            effectspeed : 2000
        }); 
    });
    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("img.lazy").trigger("lazyload")
        }, 6000); 
    });

    $(window).load(function () {
        $("html,body").trigger("scroll");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I also use this loop to load all images but in this case it load images all together.
of course I send images by viewbag from controller.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Products", "Product"))
{
 foreach (var im in ViewBag.Images)
 {
  <div class="col-md-4 product-left p-left">
   <div class="product-main simpleCart_shelfItem">
<a href="single.html" class="mask"><img class="lazy" src="~/Content/images/grey.gif" data-original="@Url.Content(im)" width="200" height="200" /></a>
<div class="product-bottom">
<h3>Smart Watches</h3>
<p>Explore Now</p>
<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i></i></a> <span class=" item_price">$ 329</span></h4>
</div>
<div class="srch srch1">
</div>
</div>
 </div>
}}

Comment: Nobody!!! seriously!!

Comment: Why nobody answer this